# apigee policy error - java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.apigee.flow.message.Message

Tags: xslt, apigee

I am trying to transform a `JSON` response from a target end point into soap message. I have 2 policies in the post flow.

1. `JSONTOXML` - If I disable `xsltransform` I see the xml result so this work.
2. `xsltransform` - this just point to my xsltransform file which has the template and dynamic content supposed to come from the xml from step 1.

Both source and output are set to "response" but it looks like it failed to cast in step 2. What should I make step 2 to pick up the xml and apply the `xsl`? How else can I do this? Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<JSONToXML async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="jsontoxml-2">
    <DisplayName>JSONtoXML-2</DisplayName>
    <FaultRules/>
    <Properties/>
    <Options>
        <NullValue>NULL</NullValue>
        <NamespaceBlockName>#namespaces</NamespaceBlockName>
        <DefaultNamespaceNodeName>$default</DefaultNamespaceNodeName>
        <NamespaceSeparator>:</NamespaceSeparator>
        <TextNodeName>#text</TextNodeName>
        <AttributeBlockName>#attrs</AttributeBlockName>
        <AttributePrefix>@</AttributePrefix>
        <InvalidCharsReplacement>_</InvalidCharsReplacement>
        <ObjectRootElementName>Root</ObjectRootElementName>
        <ArrayRootElementName>Array</ArrayRootElementName>
        <ArrayItemElementName>Item</ArrayItemElementName>
    </Options>
    <OutputVariable>response</OutputVariable>
    <Source>response</Source>
</JSONToXML>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<XSL async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="xsltransform-1">
    <DisplayName>XSLTransform-1</DisplayName>
    <FaultRules/>
    <Properties/>
    <Source>response</Source>
    <ResourceURL>xsl://xsltransform-1</ResourceURL>
    <Parameters ignoreUnresolvedVariables="true"/>
    <OutputVariable>response</OutputVariable>
</XSL>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OutputVariable cannot be set to 'response'.

Try removing the 'OutputVariable' line, or leaving it empty. Removing it, should cause the output to go to the response payload.

In other words, try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<XSL async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="xsltransform-1">
    <DisplayName>XSLTransform-1</DisplayName>
    <FaultRules/>
    <Properties/>
    <Source>response</Source>
    <ResourceURL>xsl://xsltransform-1</ResourceURL>
    <Parameters ignoreUnresolvedVariables="true"/>
</XSL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this *always* the case? Can OutputVariable never be set on response?